# Tracing stream messages in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

In my project are used Apache Camel for message routing. Messages from some nodes need to trace. For this purpose I use instance of BacklogTracer. It's ok, as long as passing message aren't InputStream. In this case the following string is received:

> [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]

For tracing stream used key "isBodyIncludeStreams". Now I get a message from an InputStream, but a stream is now read and a route looses a message for further processing.

So, the question is, how can I trace messages from an InputStream and not to lose them?

Instance of BacklogTracer:

```
val tracer = camelContext.defaultBacklogTracer as BacklogTracer
tracer.isEnabled = true
tracer.isBodyIncludeStreams = true
```

Apache Camel version: 2.24.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for streams not to be lost, you need to activate stream caching:

```
camelContext.isStreamCaching = true
```

Also, there are some more configurations for caching strategies here:
https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/stream-caching.html